# How do `intval()` and `(int)` handle whitespace?

Tags: php, integer, type-conversion

The PHP manual on [String conversion to numbers](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) says:

> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used. Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero).

This means that anything other than a number, plus or minus at the beginning of a string should return `0` when the string is converted to a number. Yet, (some) whitespace at the beginning of a string is ignored:

```
echo intval("     3");  // 3
echo intval("
3");  // 3
```

Is there any kind of whitespace that `intval()` and `(int)` do *not* strip?

Where is this behavior documented?

Comment: PHP and documentation, PHP and security, PHP and stability, … Lost cases. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The observed behavior is largely undocumented. Probably the space stripping depends on `strtod()` in C, which should use [`isspace()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isspace.html).

[`intval()` manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) says:

> The common rules of [integer casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting) apply.

Following the link (links removed):

> To explicitly convert a value to integer, use either the `(int)` or `(integer)` casts. However, in most cases the cast is not needed, since a value will be automatically converted if an operator, function or control structure requires an integer argument. A value can also be converted to integer with the `intval()` function.

So it looks like casting and `intval()` are equivalent. And a little below the quote above:

> #### From strings
>
> See [String conversion to numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

OK. Nothing really helpful there for us, except this little note:

> For more information on this conversion, see the Unix manual page for strtod(3).

Following the thread of links again, choosing the version of [`strtod()` specified in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtod.html), the API standard for UNIX.

> These functions shall convert the initial portion of the string pointed to by `nptr` to **`double`**, **`float`**, and **`long double`** representation, respectively. First, they decompose the input string into three parts:
>   1. An initial, possibly empty, sequence of white-space characters (as specified by [`isspace()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isspace.html))
>   …

Common sense tells us that this should apply to floats only because `strtod()` returns a floating point number in C, but number parsing and internal representation is quirky in PHP, as much as almost everything in this language. Who knows how it really works under the hood. Better not to know.